# redux-persist does not save state from redux-toolkit, next-redux-wrapper is used

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I am creating an application on Next js. I use redux-toolkit and next-redux-wrapper in it, I want to save the contents of my store in localStorage. But I ran into a problem - an object from redux-persist appears in the developer console, but its contents do not change when dispatch calls and store changes.

my store

```
import {
   persistStore,
   persistReducer,
   FLUSH,
   REHYDRATE,
   PAUSE,
   PERSIST,
   PURGE,
   REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'


const makeStore = () => {
   const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined';

   const rootReduser = combineReducers(
      {
         search: searchDataReduser,
         userData: userDataReduser,
         regions: regionsIdReduser,
         loading: visibleLoadingReduser,
         hotelsRegion: hotelsRegionReduser,
         hotelsId: hotelsIdReduser,
         room: roomBookingReduser,
         webRoom: webRoomBookingReduser,
         bookingRoomData: bookingRoomsUserDataReduser
      }
   )

   if (isServer) {
      const store = configureStore({
         reducer: rootReduser,
         middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
            immutableCheck: false,
            serializableCheck: false
         })
      })
      return store

   } else {

      const persistConfig = {
         key: "nextjs",
         storage
      }

      const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReduser)

      const store = configureStore({
         reducer: persistedReducer,
         middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
            immutableCheck: false,
            serializableCheck: {
               ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
            }
         })
      })

      return store
   }
}

export const store = makeStore()
export const persistor = persistStore(makeStore())
export type RootStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;
export type RootState = ReturnType<RootStore['getState']>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<ReturnType, RootState, unknown, Action>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch

export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector

export const wrapper = createWrapper<RootStore>(makeStore);
```

my app component

```
function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const loading = useAppSelector(state => state.loading.loading)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', (url) => {
      dispatch(visibleLoadingFunction(true))
    })

    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', (url) => {
      dispatch(visibleLoadingFunction(false))
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Head>
          <link rel="icon" href={'./favicon.svg'} type="image/svg" />
        </Head>
        <div className='wrapper'>
          {loading && <LoadingRouter />}
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </div>
      </PersistGate>
    </>
  )
}

App.getInitialProps = wrapper.getInitialAppProps(store => async ({ ctx, Component }) => {
  try {
//контент
  } catch (err) {
    //контент
  }

  return {
    pageProps: Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps({ ...ctx, store }) : {}
  }
})


export default wrapper.withRedux(App)
```

One of the Reduser

```
const initialState: searchStateType = {
   dataBar:
   {
      location: '',
      date: {
         from: undefined,
         to: undefined
      },
      number: {
         adults: 1,
         child: 0,
         rooms: 1
      }
   }
}

const searchDataSlice = createSlice({
   name: 'search',
   initialState,
   reducers: {
      searchbar: (state, action: PayloadAction<searchStateType>) => {
         state.dataBar = { ...action.payload.dataBar }
      }
   },
   extraReducers: {
      [HYDRATE]: (state, action) => {
         return {
            ...state,
            ...action.payload.search
         }
      }
   }
})

export const { searchbar } = searchDataSlice.actions
export default searchDataSlice.reducer
```

Comment: You are creating a store by manually calling `makeStore` and also persisting that, but then `redux-next-wrapper` will create another store on it's own and all actions dispatched/state changes go into that second store that is never persisted.

Comment: I spent two days solving this problem, can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [per the documentation](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper#usage-with-redux-persist), call `persistStore` within `makeStore`:

```js
const makeStore = () => {
  const isServer = typeof window === "undefined";

  const rootReduser = combineReducers({
    search: searchDataReduser,
    userData: userDataReduser,
    regions: regionsIdReduser,
    loading: visibleLoadingReduser,
    hotelsRegion: hotelsRegionReduser,
    hotelsId: hotelsIdReduser,
    room: roomBookingReduser,
    webRoom: webRoomBookingReduser,
    bookingRoomData: bookingRoomsUserDataReduser,
  });

  if (isServer) {
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: rootReduser,
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
          immutableCheck: false,
          serializableCheck: false,
        }),
    });
    return store;
  } else {
    const persistConfig = {
      key: "nextjs",
      storage,
    };

    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReduser);

    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: persistedReducer,
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
          immutableCheck: false,
          serializableCheck: {
            ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
          },
        }),
    });

    store.__persistor = persistStore(store); // Nasty hack

    return store;
  }
};
```

and then **remove** those top-level lines:

```js
export const store = makeStore();
export const persistor = persistStore(makeStore());
```

and in your `App` component, get the persistor from the store:

```js
<ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
  {({ store }) => (
    <PersistGate persistor={store.__persistor} loading={<div>Loading</div>}>
      <Head>
        <link rel="icon" href={"./favicon.svg"} type="image/svg" />
      </Head>
      <div className="wrapper">
        {loading && <LoadingRouter />}
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
    </PersistGate>
  )}
</ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: I tried this option, I use typescript in the project and I have an error: The property "__persistor" does not exist in the type "EnhancedStore<emptyObject & { search: searchStateType; userData: userDataType; regions: initialStateType; loading: initialStateType; ... 4 more ...; bookingRoomData: initialStateType; } & PersistPartial, AnyAction, MiddlewareArray<...>>"

Comment: please help me, what could be the problem here?

Comment: Well, the types do not know it's there - but it is. You can just tell the compiler that you know better: `(store as any).__persistor`

Comment: but unfortunately, there is still a problem: when the page is updated, the content in localStorage is updated, maybe you know what this may be related to?

Comment: That pretty much sounds like it is doing what it is supposed to do?

Comment: No, there must be a different behavior so that I don't make the state reset

Comment: Well, you have explicitly written code that says that on every `HYDRATE` action from the server, the client side state should be overwritten with the server side state (and that always starts from zero). Maybe you didn't really intend that or need to write more granular logic there?